# Running two functions on onIonChange in Ionic4 React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, ionic4, react-hook-form

I have been using react hooks form but have come in situation where i need to set the state and also call onChange method to get rid of error for which i have made a validation. Here is my code

```
<Controller
              render={({ onChange, onBlur, value }) => (
                <IonSelect
                  placeholder="Select a State"
                 
                  onIonChange={onChange}
                  onIonChange={(e:any)=>{
                    handleChange(
                      "selectedStateForBilling",
                      String(e.detail.value)
                    ); 
                  }}
                 
                >
                  {state.states.map((item) => (
                    <IonSelectOption value={item} key={item}>
                      {item}
                    </IonSelectOption>
                  ))}
                </IonSelect>
              )}
              control={control}
              name="billingState"
              defaultValue=""
              rules={{
                required: true,
              }}
            />
```

So looking at this code you may see i want to actually run two onIonChange method one for updating a state variable and the other to update the "billingState" so that i could get rid of error required:true (which is defined in my rules={{}}) is also required to throw error as for the first if users clicks on submit leaving this value empty he sees it. So is there a way i can run onChange and handleChange both in onIonChange method?

Answer (score 2):

I don't use ionic but can't you just write it like this?

```js
onIonChange={(e: any) => {
  onChange();
  handleChange(
    "selectedStateForBilling",
     String(e.detail.value)
  ); 
}}
```